# How to call HTTP endpoint with data from Data Fusion / CDAP

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm trying to call an HTTP endpoint (service/function) from my Data Fusion / CDAP real-time (streaming) pipeline. This HTTP endpoint serves a training machine learning model (via Google Cloud AI Platform Unified). I need to pass some data from my pipeline to this endpoint and ontain data back (i.e. send a chunk of pre-processed data and obtain classification result back to path it further in my Data Fusion / CDAP pipeline). How can I do it?

I've looked into:

- HTTP Plug-ins, but they support either Sink or Source, while I need a Transform plugin (i.e. data in -> call http service -> data out);
- Wrangler's invoke-http directive (https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/382107784/Invoke+HTTP+directive), but it does not support body formating and nested JSON (e.g. Cloud AI Platform serves machine learning models via nested JSON, also reply is nested JSON); also how to debug and handle errors there is not clear to me;
- python transform plug-in, but it is restrictive in terms of importing modules when run in Interpreted mode

Answer (score 0):

For your usecase, I would recommend to create a custom plugin that will use the Google Cloud AI Platform API directly, then you will have more flexibility in formating the input and output of the data.

For an example, there is a DLP plugin that communicates to Google Cloud DLP APIs: https://github.com/data-integrations/dlp-plugins